# singleTop searchable activity terminates when pressing back button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have a `ListActivity` as the main activity of my app. Items in the list should be searchable but naturally I don't want to start the same activity over and over, hence `singleTop`. However, I do want the user to be able to return to the main list after a search and that's causing me some trouble. Currently, pressing back after a search will terminate the app. One solution is to make a copy of the list activity specifically to handle searching but I can't imagine that's the best way to go about it. I have briefly tried `activity-alias` but every permutation I have tried either doesn't change the behaviour or performs a Web search instead. I don't know if `activity-alias` is even appropriate but I've included an example anyway.

My question is, is there a best way to achieve what I'm trying to do that doesn't involve superfluous code maintenance?

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainListActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity-alias
    android:name=".SearchList"
    android:targetActivity=".MainListActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity-alias>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an embarrassingly simple solution.

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainListActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

List/search activity:

```
public class MainListActivity extends FragmentActivity
implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    private boolean searching = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_cheapest);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        String[] fromColumns = {"pname", "store", "unit_price"};
        int[] toViews =
            {R.id.entryProductName, R.id.entryStore, R.id.entryUnitPrice};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.cheapest_row_entry,
            null, fromColumns, toViews);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position,
            long id) {
                searching = false;
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class).putExtra("pid", ""+id));
            }
        });
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (searching) {
            searching = false;
            getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_MAIN, null, this);
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            searching = true;
            filter = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_SEARCH, null, this);
        } else {
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_MAIN, null, this);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

However, I did first get `activity-alias` working. I'm including it for posterity.

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainListActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchListActivity" />
</activity>
<activity-alias
    android:name=".SearchListActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:targetActivity=".MainListActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"
        android:value=".SearchListActivity" />
</activity-alias>
```

List/search activity:

```
public class MainListActivity extends FragmentActivity
implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
        ...
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position,
            long id) {
                if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
                    finish();
                }
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class).putExtra("pid", ""+id));
            }
        });
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            filter = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_SEARCH, null, this);
        } else {
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_MAIN, null, this);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```